# Set up proxy for Nextjs and WordPress blog

Tags: ubuntu, virtualhost, apache2, mod-proxy, proxypass

Thanks in advance. I am new to server setup. So pardon me If I used the wrong words.

I am setting up an Ubuntu server to host Nextjs and WordPress blog on the same server.

I have to set up Nextjs on example.com and WordPress blog on example.com/blog.

Nextjs is working on localhost:3000 and the WordPress blog is on localhost:81. I used front posts to use for proxy.

Here is Apache virtual host file on Ubuntu

```
<VirtualHost *:80>      
        ServerName example.com
        
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPass /blog http://localhost:81/
        ProxyPassReverse /blog http://localhost:81/

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

After this.
example.com and example.com/blog both works fine.

But when blog post example.com/blog/post-slug open getting following error.

```
 AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.referer: http://example.com/blog
```

WordPress .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Configure your WordPress properly for the reverse proxy according to the [Moving WordPress](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/moving-wordpress/) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the information. But I already did those things. Added WordPress .htaccss file in question.

Comment: I will suggest you to use a subdomain instead of /blog directory. I think the reverse proxy of / is overwriting the /blog reverse proxy. So, Try using another subdomain or domain for each reverse proxy request or search for any other method.

Comment: Since you are proxying `/blog/` to WordPress, the path WordPress sees is `/`. Change your proxy to `ProxyPass /blog/ http://localhost:81/blog/` and `ProxyPassReverse /blog/ http://localhost:81/blog/`

Comment: Note: the trailing `/` is important.

Comment: I would not proxy WordPress. Why are you using a proxy for WordPress? Apache can be easily configured to handle WordPress locally and proxy other paths. Review the Apache `Location` directive.

Comment: @JohnHanley because it is running in a container. Anyway, you only need to configure WordPress for the correct path. It doesn't matter if it is used as a subdirectory or a subdomain. The steps to configure it are the same.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider - Where in the question does it mention containers. All important details should be included in the problem statement when posting a question.